# replace a string with double quotes and a pattern using str_replace

Tags: str-replace

i want to replace `src="images/imagename.jpg"`  to  `src="http://xyz.com/images/imagename.jpg"` 
i tried doing with str_replace. But this does seems to have issue with double quotes. Any easy solutions for this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using \ escape characters on the double quotes -- like this: \"

```
return str_replace("src=\"images/imagename.jpg\"", "src=\"http://xyz.com/images/imagename.jpg\"", $string);
```

With a string passed through htmlentities:

```
return str_replace("src=&quot;images/imagename.jpg&quot;", "src=&quot;http://xyz.com/images/imagename.jpg&quot;", $string);
```

Comment: I have tried that too  $string =htmlentities('src="images/imagename.jpg"');
echo str_replace('src=\"images/', "http://xyz.com/images/imagename.jpg", $string); but that does not work

Comment: htmlentities would have changed the double quotes to &quot;

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a replacement of a post-htmlentities string.